# Enable keyboard Search key when Speech to Text ends in map searchBar

Tags: swift, keyboard, speech-to-text, searchbar

When activating the map searchbar and typing in a town name the ‘search’ key  activates and goes blue, if however you enter data using speech-to-text, the button is grey. If you touch the button the ‘keyboard’ click can be heard but the button does nothing. I have tried detecting when the STT has ended with the code below without success, can anybody help please. I should add that if I use STT in a textfield that behaves as expected and ‘done’ button turns blue.

```
func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("Its here = searchBarShouldEndEditing")
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("Its here = searchBarTextDidEndEditing")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to iOS 16.1 and now keyboard behaves as expected and 'search' button turns blue after STT ends.